# Unable to typing more than 1 character in input for FormArray within a FormArray for Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am thinking this could be a bug for Reactive Form. I would appreciate any help from more experienced Angular Experts.

Symptom: Unable to key in more than 1 character in input at given time.

Occurrence: When input is a FormArray within a FormArray

I have included a Plunker link as below:
https://embed.plnkr.co/zl2BQe/.

```
//app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
export class AppModule { }

//app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  testForm: FormGroup; 

  ngOnInit(){
   this.testForm = new FormGroup({
   'lines': new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      'fields': new FormArray([
        new FormControl('')
      ])
     })
    ])
   })
  }

onAddLine(){
if(this.testForm.value.lines.length<10){
  (<FormArray>this.testForm.get('lines')).push(
    new FormGroup({
      'fields': new FormArray([
        new FormControl()
      ])
     })
   )
 }
}

onAddField(){
  // Not developed       
 }
}

//app.component.html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    Angular Reactive FormArray Error 
    <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddField()">Add 
    Field</button>-->
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddLine()">Add 
    Line</button>
  </div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <form [formGroup]="testForm">
    <div class="form-inline" *ngFor="let line of testForm.value.lines; let i = index" formArrayName="lines">
      <div class="form-group">
        <span [formGroupName]="i">
          <span *ngFor="let field of testForm.value.lines[0].fields; let j = index" formArrayName="fields">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="j">
              Please Type on Input Field
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13327

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Cause**

You get this problem because you rely on `formGroup.value` which gets a new instance when any of the input value changes. Therefore your control tree will be recreated in DOM thus loosing the focus.

The steps which create this problem are:

- you change the input which reflect the value directly to the
  `FormControl` value
- the `formGroup.value` changes
- `*ngFor` iterates over the new value and creates new elements removing the old ones
- the new element will have the previous element value but not the focus

**Why *ngFor creates new elements**

`NgFor` creates new elements because of `trackBy` which is by default the enumerated value. If the value changes, the element from DOM, which is tracked by the older value, is considered to be obsolete, thus being removed, and a new element is created for the new value. Even if the value appears to be the same, it is not, is just another instance of `FormControl`, as you are actually enumerating over the `FormControl`s.

In your case:
`*ngFor="let line of testForm.value.lines;...`
and
`*ngFor="let field of testForm.value.lines[0].fields;...`
are incorrect for this reason.

**Solution**

[Here is an updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JwJrCHeIsigrcNTgAN10?p=preview).

Therefore the template should look like:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      Angular Reactive FormArray Error 
      <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddField()">Add Field</button>-->
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddLine()">Add Line</button>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form [formGroup]="testForm">
        <div class="form-inline" *ngFor="let line of testForm.get('lines').controls; let i = index" formArrayName="lines">
          <div class="form-group">
            <span [formGroupName]="i">
              <span *ngFor="let field of line.get('fields').controls; let j = index" formArrayName="fields">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="j">
                  Please Type on Input Field
              </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi andreim, I am grateful for your help. Thank you.

Comment: Note that this `testForm.controls['lines'].controls[i].controls['fields'].controls` can be easily replaced by: `testForm.get('lines.' + i + '.fields').controls` :)

Comment: @developer033 Thanks! You are right, there is the `get()` method. I changed the answer to reflect this. So the 1st loop is `testForm.get('lines').controls` and the second is `line.get('fields').controls`. Much clearer now. I should pay more attention to how ugly the code might get :)