# Reactive form, Array mat-table CDK

Tags: angular, angular-material

I fronting a very weird problem... I'm trying to make a form (Via Reactive form) with some dynamic array fields, everything works fine except that I can't go and edit these fields... It looks like I lose the focus every time I click on it. I made a Stackblitz for more information : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3actx

I use Angular 5 and Angular material

Thank you

Comment: try autofocus attribute in input field

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution on this post : [Unable to typing more than 1 character in input for FormArray within a FormArray for Reactive Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677098/unable-to-typing-more-than-1-character-in-input-for-formarray-within-a-formarray)

The problem was that I used the form.value as datas for the mat-table, so when I clicked on a field, the table refresh and so I lost my focus.